# Cart API V3: Can't create a Cart for product that has options

Tags: bigcommerce

When I create a cart with products without options, everything works fine, but if any of the products has product option, it doesn't work
Here I got the product options, it has one option with id 21

[image]

When I use this option id in creating the API, it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this in v2? This could be a bug in v3, which is pretty new still.

Comment: V2 doesn't have Cart api I think

Comment: V2 has the Orders API which can be used to create an order.  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#create-an-order

Comment: I don't want to create an order, I want to create a cart and generate a URL and then move the customer to this URL where he can finish the payment, the shipping and place the order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding a product to the cart that has a single modifier associated with it (like a text field) try the POST to the cart API without including the "variant_id" field:

```
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "product_id": 1001,
      "option_selections": [
        {
          "option_id": 123,
          "option_value": "Hello!"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If your product has one option (like a radio button) associated with it, try this request, using just the variant ID to identify the option:

```
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "product_id": 1001,
      "variant_id": 2331
    }
]
}
```

If your product has both an option (radio button) and a modifier (text field), this sample request should work. The first option selection corresponds to the radio button option and the second option selection corresponds to the text field modifier. No variant id is included:

```
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "product_id": 101,
      "option_selections": [
        {
          "option_id": 231,
          "option_value": 456
        },

        {
          "option_id": 123,
          "option_value": "Hello!"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

For context on the v3 terminology, both options and modifiers are terms for lists of choices attached to products, but options are choices that are used to build out variants (SKUs) and modifiers are choices that are not tied to variants at all. This is why a text field would be a modifier, and a radio button would be an option.

Comment: This is the response after removing the variant_id   {
    "status": 422,
    "title": "Missing or incorrect required fields",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes",
    "errors": {
        "variant": "This product has options, variant ID is required"
    }
}

Comment: The option response in your original post looks like it is for a modifier, not an option. Could you confirm whether you've made any changes to the text field choice associated with that product before trying the request without the variant_id? I'll edit my response to include sample requests for products with an option, products with a modifier, and products with a combination of both.

Comment: Yes, it is a modifier, so please show me how to send a modifier and an option in the body

Comment: The third code sample shows a cart body with both a modifier and an option (for example, a product that has an option for size and also a text field to enter a custom monogram). The first code sample shows a modifier by itself, and the second body shows an option by itself.