# How to add modifiers to cart line item in BigCommerce Api

Tags: api, cart, bigcommerce

I already tried the solution given in this [Cart API V3: Can't create a Cart for product that has options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619331/cart-api-v3-cant-create-a-cart-for-product-that-has-options) link but it's not working for me.

modifier is extra fitting added to the product like "name tag" for suitcase.

I tried to add the modifier in "option_selections" like below but it returns 422 error.

Request:

```
{
  "quantity":"1",
  "product_id":"5846",
  "variant_id":150922,
  "list_price":" 170.00",
  "option_selections":[{"option_id":23800, "option_value":"10088"}]
}
```

Response:
StatusCode: 422, ReasonPhrase: 'Unprocessable Entity'

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: You mentioned you tried the solution in the linked question didn't work for you--did you try omitting the variant_id in your request? It also looks like the option_value should be a number rather than a string.

Comment: Yes, i did tried omitting variant_id but i'm getting the same error. here modifier i'm trying to add is not an option which creates a variant. It's an extra items offer with the product for extra amount. like mobile case with mobile.

Comment: Could you share the response you get if you make a request to the modifiers endpoint for that product? /products/{productID}/modifiers

You'll also get an error if you don't include the line items array. It should look like:
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "product_id": 1235,
      "option_selections": [
        {
          "option_id": 495,
          "option_value": 834
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Modifiers looks like: {"id" : 21506,"product_id" : 76,"name" : "Seat Cover Product Pick List","display_name" : "Choose Seat Cover","type" : "product_list_with_images" ,"required" : false,"config" : null,"option_values" : [{"id" : 10090,"option_id" : 21506,"label" : "Seat Cover - Blue & Black","sort_order" : 2,"is_default" : false,"adjusters" : {"price" : null,"weight" : null,"image_url" : "","purchasing_disabled" : {"status" : false,"message" : ""}},"value_data" : {"product_id" : 81 } }]}

Comment: my request data exactly follows the structure given here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/cart/server-to-server-cart/add-cart-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a new cart, try this request body (POST to /carts endpoint):

```
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "product_id": 76,
      "list_price": 170.00,
      "option_selections": [
        {
          "option_id": 21506,
          "option_value": 10090
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You shouldn't have quotes around any of these field values--list_price, product_id, etc all accept a number, not a string.

If you want to add a new line item to an existing cart, you can use the same request body as above. The request will be a POST to `carts/{cartID}/items`

EDIT:
If you are updating a line item that already exists in the cart, you'll want to make a PUT to `/carts/{cartID}/items/{itemID}`.

Request body:

```
{
  "line_item": {
    "quantity": 1,
    "product_id": 76,
    "list_price": 170.00,
    "option_selections": [
      {
        "option_id": 21506,
        "option_value": 10090
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: it does need to be "line_item" rather than "line_items" when updating a single cart item. I'll work with our documentation team to get this updated in the API reference.

Comment: I'm getting {
    "status": 405,
    "title": "Method Not Allowed",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes",
    "detail": "The requested HTTP method is invalid for this endpoint."
}

Comment: Are you making a POST to /carts?

Comment: Yes Karen, i'm making a POST call as they told in this link https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/cart/server-to-server-cart/add-cart-items

Comment: @sasireka I wasn't clear whether you were creating a new cart, adding an item to an existing cart, or modifying an existing cart item. I edited my answer with sample requests for all 3 scenarios. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Karen,  I'm trying both create cart and add item to existing cart. what you suggested is to add an item with option to the cart, but i need to add modifiers with product.

Comment: @sasireka All of the examples above are for a product with one modifier associated with it. Modifier values should still be listed in the "option_selections" array, and products with modifiers should not include "variant_id" in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, though I agree with Karen White's answer, I wanted to add a product which has options like colors and modifiers too. Which I was not able to achieve with that. I used the following data to add product with option and modifier.
Instead of passing `variant_id`, pass variant as option (option_id gets option's id and option_value gets option value's id) and pass modifier as option (modifier option_id gets option's id and option_value gets option value's id)

```
{
    "line_items": [{
        "quantity": 1,
        "product_id": 5846,
        "option_selections": [{
            "option_id": 23799,
            "option_value": 10173
        }, {
            "option_id": 23800,
            "option_value": 10088
        }]
    }]
}
```