# Get Field option via API

Tags: bigcommerce

I set a product option (a text field) on my product. The purpose is to collect user data that will be used in the cart and to fulfill the the order after checkout.

I will share what I am trying but open to any way to get user input from the product page to be used on the cart and the order data.

### My Products option tab

[image]

### my attempt to get this field via api

`GET: https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/2bihpr2wvz/v3/catalog/products/114/options`

response:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "meta": {}
}
```

returns nothing as if the option does not exist.

Ultimately. I just need my users to provide a string that will be used in the cart and can also be used in the order.json... How do i add it to cart (using api)? do variants come in to play here?

### edit

Like Karen said; text fields are considered a modifier sense there is no variant or sku change.

when i `PUT: 2bihpr2wvz/v3/catalog/products/115/modifiers/113` to change the modifier value; what should the body look like. I am trying below.

```
{
    "option_values": [
        {
            "id": 113,
            "value_data": {
                "build_id": "test_build_id"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

sometime i get `The product is currently associated with an option set, please remove it before editing an option or modifier.` but that might fix when the body is formatted correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text fields are considered modifier options in the v3 catalog API. Try making a request to the `/v3/catalog/products/114/modifiers` endpoint, and you should see the data returned.

A quick note on options vs modifiers--In the v3 catalog API, we make a distinction between the 2 types of choices that can be attached to products:

- Variant options are choices that are used to build out SKUs, like size or color.
- Modifier options are choices that are not tied to SKUs at all. For example, a text field where the shopper enters text for custom embroidery, a file upload field, or a checkbox to add insurance to the order.

The modifier text field value will show in the order and cart responses, but you will need to add a query parameter to the cart request to get option data for the line items, like this:

```
/v3/carts/{cartID}?include=line_items.physical_items.options
```

To add a product with a modifier to the cart, make sure that you omit the variant_id in the cart body. There are a couple of sample requests in my answer here that might be helpful:

[Cart API V3: Can't create a Cart for product that has options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619331/cart-api-v3-cant-create-a-cart-for-product-that-has-options)

Comment: Thank you Karen. I just figured this out also... But i cant find too much on modifiers. When i update the modifier at `PUT: v3/catalog/products/115/modifiers/113` what should the `body` look like. I will update my question to show what i am trying now

Comment: Hi Omar, a text field modifier would normally have a blank `option_values` array because the option value is entered by the shopper on the storefront (or programmatically if using the /carts API). Are you trying to do something like pre-fill a value in the text field?

Comment: yes the value is not actually updated by the user. I will be doing it behind the scene based on user activity... it will be generated ID on the fly

Comment: In that case, I think the best bet would be to use JS on the storefront to either populate the value on the product details page or use the cart API to update the options array on the cart line item--it sort of depends on what kind of user activity you're listening for. In the future, we're looking at providing cart metafields that would let you store arbitrary key/value pairs on the cart entities themselves.

Comment: Hmm. Is it wrong to update modifier values before addtocart? It seems like I would need to in order for that product in the cart to have the appropriate value. I’m only using stencil for cart. Everything else is API

Comment: I don't know about wrong, although it could be an odd user experience depending on whether or not the text field has been hidden on the product details page :) It might be a better experience to get the cart ID after the user adds the product to the cart and then use that to update the cart line item with the option value. Logistically, either way should work though, if the goal is to assign the value and persist it through to the order.

Comment: Ok. Just one more question. Either way can u update ur answer to include update instructions via api. Thank you for ur help.